# Ajax custom search

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, api

I'm trying to retrieve data from a JSON file that has a limit of 200 but has a total records of 2323. My co-worker has set up the following *search header* that I need to set up a search for so it'll pull more data than the set 200 limit. Sorry if it's confusing. This is all new to me.

Search header

```
if ($request->first_name) {
            $qb->andWhere($qb->expr()->like('`First Name`', ':first_name'))
                ->setParameter('first_name', '%' . str_replace('%', '', $request->first_name) . '%');
        }
```

AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '*path*',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data)
        }
    })
```

Contents of JSON file (2 examples):

```
"page": 1,
  "start": 0,
  "limit": 200,
  "total": 2323,
  "data": [{
      "FairviewID": "2",
      "First Name": "John",
      "Middle Name": "R",
      "Last Name": "Smith",
      "Address": null,
      "City": null,
      "State": null
    },
    {
      "FairviewID": "1",
      "First Name": "John 2",
      "Middle Name": "R 2",
      "Last Name": "Smith 2",
      "Address": null,
      "City": null,
      "State": null
     }
]
```

Comment: The code in the beginning is PHP and not JS.

Comment: Yes. That's already in place on the server. I just need a search that'll work with it @mplungjan